# How to load audio file in ListView?

Tags: android, listview, audio

I need to load random audio files from storage, into my ListView, on a button click. But I don't understand how can I do this. When I call intent, file manager open to pick file. My song must have title, artist name and url. But after clicking it doesn't add. This is my code. Don't scold me for a possibly dull question. I'm new at android developing.

```
    private fun loadSong() {
    val intent: Intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).apply {
        type = "audio/*"
        action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
    }
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Audio"), PICK_AUDIO)
}

        override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == PICK_AUDIO && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            if (data != null) {
                audioUri = data.data
                
            }
        }
        adapter = SongsAdapter(listSongs)
        twoTracksListView.adapter = adapter
    }
```

Comment: 1st you need to add permission in your manifest then check storage  permission

Comment: Separate it into two problems 1) showing some fake data you want in a ListView, then 2) Getting the data you want from Android.  (finally, 3) put them both together)

Comment: Ramesh I have already do this

Comment: Blundell, whi I need to show fake data?